# Django shortcut get_object_or_404 inside Django Rest framework Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The **get_object_or_404** shortcut function in Django when encountering an exception gives a very nice error message in the following format:

```
'No %s matches the given query.' % queryset.model._meta.object_name)
```

However, while using this inside a DRF 3.X Class based view, the final 404 response data has a very stripped down version, which is as follows:

```
{"detail": "Not found."}
```

As is evident, the DRF message is very generic with no information about the Model name.I am assuming that the DRF **NotFound** Exception class defined [here](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/exceptions.py#L185) strips down the message to its current bare minimum.

How can I get the original nice error message that Django returns in-spite of using it within a DRF Class Based View ?

Comment: I don't think so. DRF api responses are very standard much, and sharing bare minimum message when these is an error should be fine :) .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The default exception handler for an [`APIView`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/903204cd7926e9e6ceaaec1bfbf1ba3ed3330ca4/rest_framework/views.py#L106) class is decided by the [`get_exception_handler`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/903204cd7926e9e6ceaaec1bfbf1ba3ed3330ca4/rest_framework/views.py#L296) method. Ie,

```
def get_exception_handler(self):
    """
    Returns the exception handler that this view uses.
    """
    return self.settings.EXCEPTION_HANDLER
```

In other words the handler function that an `APIView` class use by default is [`rest_framework.views.exception_handler`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/903204cd7926e9e6ceaaec1bfbf1ba3ed3330ca4/rest_framework/views.py#L73)(Which is specified on the [`default settings`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/903204cd7926e9e6ceaaec1bfbf1ba3ed3330ca4/rest_framework/settings.py#L89)).

As per the DRF Doc,

> By default DRF handle the REST framework `APIException`, and
>   alsoDjango's built-in `Http404` and `PermissionDenied` exceptions.

Since in this case you want to customize the error message only for the `Http404`, you can create your own handler like this.

ie,

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    # Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
    # to get the standard error response.
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    # Now overide the error message.
    if response is not None and isinstance(exc, Http404):
        # set the custom message data on response object
        response.data['detail'] =  exc.args[0] # exc.args[0] will have the message text, 

    return response
```

Then place this custom handler in your project settings.

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Note: **This solution is not tested.**

Comment: I get an import module error when I specify the handler in the settings.py..where exactly should be the location of the file where in which i write the exception handler ?

Comment: @Amistad How did you currently set the `EXCEPTION_HANDLER`?

Comment: ..the details are here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53257145/location-for-django-rest-framework-exception-handler