# Location for Django Rest framework exception handler

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

The DRF Docs say that once an exception handler is set up, it needs to be defined in the **settings.py** as follows:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

My Django project layout is like this:

```
backend
    settings.py
    connectivity_service
        utils
            Custom404ErrorMessage.py
```

The project is called backend and the app name is connectivity_service.The Custom404ErrorMessage.py file contains the function **custom_exception_handler** which handles the exception.

My settings.py looks like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'backend.connectivity_service.utils.Custom404ErrorMessage'
}
```

However, this gives me the following error message:

```
ImportError: Could not import 'backend.connectivity_service.utils.Custom404ErrorMessage' 
for API setting 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER'. ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 
'backend.connectivity_service'.
```

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You may need to point it to your exception handling function, i.e. "backend.connectivity_service.utils.Custom404ErrorMessage.custom_exception_handler"

Comment: tried that..does not work..strangely the error is **ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'backend.connectivity_service'**. Looks like it is not able to import the project and app also. However, everything else in terms of the ORM, Views etc works.Only this section of the **settings.py** does not work.

Comment: can you add complete tree structure?

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too and what you need to do to solve is this:

1. create utils.py inside your app folder
2. define your custom_exception_handler function inside it
3. in your setting file add this " 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler' ", no need to type my_project

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that you confused the text when translating from the [DRF example](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling) to your code. The docs state:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
# Call REST framework's default exception handler first,
# to get the standard error response.
response = exception_handler(exc, context)

# Now add the HTTP status code to the response.
if response is not None:
    response.data['status_code'] = response.status_code

return response
```

Then it tells you to add it to your settings as:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Keep in mind that the example above has the following folder structure:

my_project > my_app > utils > custom_exception_handler

Which translates to:

my_project_FOLDER > my_app_FOLDER > utils.PY > NAME_OF_DEFINED_FUNCTION_THAT_HANDLES_EXCEPTIONS

That's how I think you might have gotten confused. So you have `Custom404ErrorMessage.py` inside a **utils_FOLDER** and are trying to import that instead of the defined function itself. Unless of course that `Custom404ErrorMessage.py` is a class, but I doubt it since you seemed to be following the linked DRF example which uses a function.

I assume that your **Custom404ErrorMessage.py** has the following:

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
....
```

So for your set up, your **settings.py** would look like this:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
 'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 'backend.connectivity_service.utils.Custom404ErrorMessage.custom_exception_handler'
 }
```

See how the last part is the defined function? Hope that helps!